# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:8000 when making call form one container to another

Tags: javascript, python, docker

I have very simple django rest app and cucumber tests (written on JS) which has to test the rest endpoints. I'm trying to create container for rest app and when it is running, I want to create another container for the tests which has to make calls the the rest ednpoints (running from the first container) but then I getting this error `connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:8000` for each test. Here is my Dockerfile for rest app

```
FROM python:3.8
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RUN mkdir -p /app/src
WORKDIR /app/src
COPY requirements.txt /app/src
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
COPY . /app/src
```

And here is my cucumber test Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12
WORKDIR /app/src
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["yarn", "cucumber-drf"]
```

Here is my Docker-compose file

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  test:
    build: ./cucumber_drf_tests
    image: cucumber_test
    container_name: cucumber_container
    ports:
      - 8001:8000
    depends_on:
      - app
  app:
    build: .
    image: app:django
    container_name: django_rest_container
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    expose:
      - 8000
    volumes:
    - .:/django #describes a folder that resides on our OS within the container
    command: >
      bash -c "python manage.py migrate
      && python manage.py loaddata ./project_apps/fixtures/dummy_data.json
      && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres_db
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
```

And i give example with one of my test calls

```
When('I sent a get request to {string}', async function (path) {
this.res = await axiosInst.get('http://app:8000', config.user);
this.getUserData = this.res.data;
```

});

But for some unknown reason it is trying to connect to `0.0.0.0:8000`. If I run the tests locally they pass. Please help!

Comment: Have you confirmed that you are able to send requests to `app` from your host machine, e.g. `curl -vX GET http://localhost:8000` returns a response? Also, keep in mind that `depends_on` does not wait for the server in `app` to be started. Your tests will start as soon as they can, while you may still be running migrations or loading data in `app`. You can do `docker-compose up app`, wait until you are sure the server has started, and then run `docker-compose up test`. See if that makes any difference.

Comment: Yes, I have, when I run  the the server form the  app container and run the tests, but locally from the host machine, they pass. I checked, the migrations, the script and starting the app server are first, and then it starts to built the test container end run the commands inside it. I think it is something with the urls, all containers are running on the same network.

Comment: I notice that you are also exposing port 8000 on your cucumber service (`8001:8000`). What happens if you stop doing that? You also shouldn't need both the `ports` and `expose` directives, one or the other is fine (just a note, probably not the issue).

Comment: Yeah, I have tried without `expose` statement at all and it the same issue